# How to fix Memory allocation for BOW in python

Tags: python, memory, nlp

Bag of words process does not depend on other recprds such as TF-IDF

so i wonder if there is a way allows me to do BOW in batches

here is my code

```
def BOW(df):
  CountVec = CountVectorizer() # to use only  bigrams ngram_range=(2,2)
  Count_data = CountVec.fit_transform(df)
  cv_dataframe=pd.DataFrame(Count_data.toarray(),columns=CountVec.get_feature_names())
  return cv_dataframe.astype(np.uint8)


dfMethod = BOW(df_reps["Txt"])
```

the error i got is

> MemoryError: Unable to allocate 21.4 GiB for an array with shape
> (87148, 32996) and data type int64

Anyone did this before and know a better way to do that?

how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At which line it is throwing MemoryError? Is it `cv_dataframe=pd.DataFrame(...` here? If yes, try to optimize the data type of `Count_data` first.

Like,

```
Count_data = Count_data.astype(np.uint8)
```

Note: This is just one way to reduce the overall memory size.

Some more enhancements,

```
def BOW(df):
  CountVec = CountVectorizer() # to use only  bigrams ngram_range=(2,2)
  Count_data = CountVec.fit_transform(df)
  Count_data = Count_data.astype(np.uint8)
  # del df # if it is not needed in further steps
  cv_dataframe=pd.DataFrame(Count_data.toarray(),columns=CountVec.get_feature_names())
  return cv_dataframe # removed data type conversion
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking into the usage of the `min_df` parameter to make working with the document-term matrix more tractable, you are likely keeping a lot of tokens which aren't predictive. Set this to a higher value when you initialize your `CountVectorizer`.

Also, if you are converting to a dataframe you can use [Sparse data structures](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/sparse.html) which should save on memory usage.